# Find an invertible real matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP$ is diagonal where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an invertible real matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP$ is diagonal  where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

My attempt : Here $Ch_A=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$.

$Ax=\lambda x$ where $x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\end{bmatrix}$

If $\lambda =2$ ,then $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 x_1 \\2x_2\end{bmatrix}$

$x_1+2x_2=2x_1$ and $2x_2=2x_2 \implies 2x_2-2x_2=0 \implies x_2=0$

Now put $x_2=0$ in $x_1+2x_2=2x_1 \implies  x_1=0$

Similarly ,If $\lambda =1$ ,then $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\end{bmatrix}$

$x_1+2x_2=x_1$ and $2x_2=x_2 \implies 2x_2-x_2=0 \implies x_2=0$

Now put $x_2=0$ in $x_1+2x_2=x_1 \implies  x_1=0$

Therefore , $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

I think $P^{-1}$= not exist

Comment: Whenever you have an equation $2x_2-2x_2=0$, this means that ANY value of $x_2$ works, since this is the same as $0=0$. This does not imply $x_2=0$.

Comment: Same for the second part where you have $x_1=x_1$, which you claim implies $x_1=0$. This in fact means $x_1$ can be ANY value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is found by finding:-

$$Null(A-I)=Null\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\right)=span(\{(1,0)^{T}\}$$.

As you get only $x_{2}=0$ as the equation . So the solution space is the span of $(1,0)^{T}$

Similarly the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=2$ is found by

$$Null(A-2I)=Null\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$.

So $-x_{1}+2x_{2}=0\implies x_{1}=2x_{2}$

So the eigenspace is $span(\{(2,1)^{T}\})$

So the matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$.

And $D=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$.

In general if a $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigen values then it is always diagonalizable.